# How to run AWS SDK Opsworks Commands in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-opsworks

I've got a very simple lambda function trying to use the AWS SDK to call opsworks.describeInstances. The code executes locally fine, however inside lambda, it times out with no error or feedback.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var opsworks = new AWS.OpsWorks({
    apiVersion: 'latest',
    region: "us-east-1"
});
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var params = {
        LayerId: 'idoflayer'
    };
    opsworks.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, data);
    });
};
```

The lambda policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "opsworks:CreateDeployment",
                "opsworks:DescribeDeployments",
                "opsworks:DescribeLayers",
                "opsworks:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've increased both memory and timeout. The logs only show that function is being called, no output. The monitoring of the lambda function shows Invocation errors, but I think this is just due to the timeout. I'm running this in us-west-2, but I've also tried running it in us-east-1, same result.

Any ideas? I'd love to use lambda to monitor and manage OpsWorks.

Comment: Timeouts like this are most commonly caused by placing the Lambda function within a VPC which doesn't have a NAT gateway. Lambda functions with VPC access do not get public IP addresses, so you are required to have a NAT gateway if you want your Lambda function to access anything outside the VPC, such as the AWS Opsworks API.

Comment: Thanks Mark B, yes I was running inside VPC and that was issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve, I just removed the custom VPC settings, since the function was only trying to access the AWS Opsworks API. Also noticed this inside the documentation:

> When you enable VPC, your Lambda function will lose default internet access. If you require external internet access for your function, ensure that your security group allows outbound connections and that your VPC has a NAT gateway.

Since Lambda bundles the SDK to be available inside functions and access is determined by IAM policies, it is a little confusing that you still need external access to the internet to use the API.

Comment: You don't need "external access to the internet" in order to use the AWS API, you need external access to anything that isn't part of your VPC. The wording in the documentation could be clearer. Note that you can access S3 with only VPC access, via VPC endpoints. Hopefully they will add more VPC service endpoints in the future.