# Timeout connecting to OpsWorks from a lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm writing a lambda function to try to connect to an endpoint on all instances running under a given OpsWorks layer. My issue is that the function times out when I try to test it. There's no other error listed in the output, so I'm not sure where to begin debugging this issue.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400017/how-to-run-aws-sdk-opsworks-commands-in-aws-lambda) StackOverflow question, and I tried creating the function without a VPC, but the issue persists (the OpsWorks stack in question is behind a VPC).

The lambda code in question is:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var done = false; 

    var awsOptions = {
        region: 'us-east-1'
    };

    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var opsWorks = new AWS.OpsWorks(awsOptions);

    var appIds = ["MY_APP_ID"];
    var layerIds = ["MY_LAYER_ID"];
    var stackId = "MY_STACK"

    var isOnline = function(instance) {
        return instance.Status == 'online';
    }

    console.log("Have all the variables set up, time to run...");

    opsWorks.describeLayers({StackId: stackId, LayerIds: layerIds}, 
        function(error, layers) {

        console.log("Described the layer...");
        console.log(layers);

        opsWorks.describeInstances({LayerId: layers[0].LayerId}, 
            function(err, instances) {

            console.log("Described the instances on the layer");
            if (err) {
                console.error("No instances found!");
            }

            console.log("No errors, keep going...");
            instances.Instances.filter(isOnline).forEach(function(instance) {

                console.log("Filtered out the offline instances.");
                var options = {
                    method: "GET",
                    path: "/endpoint",
                    port: 123,
                    timeout: 10000,
                    url: instance.Hostname    
                };

                http.request(options, function(response) {

                    if (response.statusCode != 200) {

                        console.error("Instance " + instance.InstanceId 
                            + " is not responding!");

                    } else {

                        console.log("Got a response, time to do stuff!");

                    }
                });

            });

            done = true;

        });
    });

    while (!done) {
        // Keep waiting...
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

I resolved the similar issue I was facing by 2 ways :

1. Removed VPC (which you already mentioned you have tried it)
2. JS code issue, what happens is that if JS code encounters an error, it stops executing the lambda function, and it kind of freezes the lambda, and it times out after the timeout you might have specified in your lambda console. In my case, I didnt declared a variable and started using it and got the timeout error, but when I declared it and resolved some other JS related errors, it worked like a charm.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I wound up giving up on Node and writing it in Java, which wound up working for me.